# Inverse problem and heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, hyperbolic-equations, parabolic-pde

In several books dealing with the subject of evolution equations we always find this expression: 'the equation of heat is irreversible in time' or 'the equation of the waves is reversible in time'.
This expression means what? My first impression when I read this expression is: can we find the initial state of the system from the final state (inverse problem).
is it true ?
Thank you.

Comment: I think what is meant is that in the solution for the wave equation you can substitute $t$ with $-t$ and obtain the same solution, which as you said goes from the final state to the initial state of the system. You cannot do this with the heat equation because the fundamental solution of the heat equation in $\mathbb{R^n}$ takes the form $$u(\mathbf{x},t)=(4\pi t)^{-n/2}e^{-\frac{\left<\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\right>}{4t}}$$ and as you can see if you input negative time you get a complex result, which is of course non physical. But I'm not an expert and I suggest you wait for an answer from one.

Comment: This translates the fundamental fact that diffusion is irreversible, i.e. the second law of thermodynamics.

Comment: Thanks guys, but is the wave is reversible?( I talk in the  physical sens)...by the way what does mean revesible in physics? Can tou give me some examples.? thank you

Comment: physically, you can imagine that you could see a wave propagating on a string in both directions and it wouldn't look strange, while if you saw a metal bar with homogeneous temperature suddenly and spontaneously heating up in the middle to assume some temperature profile, that would certainly be non physical

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if *reversible* is a technical term, but I'd interpret it the way you did.

**Wave equation.** It's clear that if $u$ is a solution of $u_{tt} = \Delta u$, then $v(t,x) = u(-t,x)$ is also a solution. Thus we can reverse the time. Given any initial conditions $f \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $g \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, the problem 
$$
\begin{cases}
u_{tt} = \Delta u \\
u(0,\cdot) = f \\
u_t(0,\cdot) = g
\end{cases}
$$
has a solution defined not only on $[0,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}^n$, but even on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n$ (i.e., for all times $t \in \mathbb{R}$); the usual formula works. Then one can take $u(-1,\cdot)$ and $u_t(-1,0)$ as initial conditions and obtain $f,g$ at time $1$.

**Heat equation.** The same trick $t \mapsto -t$ doesn't work here. Also, one cannot solve the inverse problem in general. The formula for the solution implies that it's a smooth function for all $t>0$. Therefore you can take some function $u_0 \in C_c^2(\mathbb{R}^n) \setminus C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to be an initial condition (which is perfectly valid even in the classical sense), but finding a solution $u \colon [0,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $u(t,\cdot) = u_0$ for some $t>0$ is impossible.

As a side comment, I've never really understood how this irreversibility pops up when one derives the heat equation from the kinetic equations (i.e. as a limit of the model with finitely many colliding particles).